# x11 clipboard not available after quitting vim

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, vim

While I'm running an instance of Vim (version 7.4, in the terminal) I can copy text into the + (Primary Selection) and * (Clipboard Selection) registers. If I switch to another program in a new window/terminal I can paste from these buffers without issue.

i.e.

- in terminal one I'm running vim and yank into +,* buffers
- in terminal two I'm in bash and xclip -o pastes the content of the * buffer
- in my firefox instance <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> pastes the contents of the + buffer

If I quit vim then the clipboard is purged.

- xclip -o will output `Error: target STRING not available`
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> does nothing in Firefox

If I suspend the vim process (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd>) I get the same result as if I had quit vim. Resuming the process (fg) does not return access to the x11 clipboards, I have to yank to the registers again. This sort of usage is especially bothersome for me.

Is there anything I can do to change this? I'm a novice vim/linux user.

Comment: Not that I know of (I basically keep Vim open in such cases as a workaround), but some explanation can be found at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ClipboardPersistence. Basically, the clipboard is not persistent by default, and the applications need to put in some effort to _really_ copy to the clipboard. Vim apparently does not.

Comment: the characters * and + are not system-wide -- they are only recognised by VIM (and shared by it while it is running).